# Matlab Java engine API error

Tags: java, matlab

I was trying to connect Matlab with Java  using the Matlab Engine,
I followed the examples  of this web page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/execute-matlab-functions-from-java.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

After adding the requiered references and writting down this code:

```
import com.mathworks.engine.*;
public class CNN
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab();
        double[] a = {2.0 ,4.0, 6.0};
        double[] roots = eng.feval("sqrt", a);
        eng.close();
    }
}
```

Eclipse shows an error on feval function

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj64D.png)

It seems that I am using wrong arguments on the feval function.
But  I am using the code posted on the reference page of mathworks.

All the other example codes  do not compile.

what am I doing wrong ? if the documentation is wrong how can I know  how to use this function?

Comment: Try using ``Double[] a = ...`` and ``Double[] roots = ...``. As the error messages states, ``feval(...)`` can only act on arrays of Java objects, and ``double`` is a primitive.

Comment: @Antares42 So to you mean just changing  that word of the code ?
Sorry   I am new on Java

Comment: Yes, the error message appears to imply that. ``Double`` is an object-style wrapper around the primitive type ``double``, and since the method ``feval(...)`` expects to be called with an array of objects (not primitives), that should solve it.